Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages
While upgrading my Ubuntu 22.04 something went wrong on the screen while booting the machine.
I tried to update the packages, but I'm still unable to install all the dependencies.



Have you tried sudo apt -f install?

Yes I tried but still same error showing

Does this answer your question? E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages

I tried to open log file by using nano command but file is empty
